# C# Topmost=true - restrict to application

Tags: c#, winforms

Our Application is displaying an "update-hint", if a new version is available.

This Update-hint should be "topmost" within the application, but, if the application is minimized, or send to the background, the update-hint should vanish as well..

Just using

```
this.TopMost = true;
```

will overlay "ANY" application that is currently running...

Is there a way to just "overlay" windows generated by the current application?

---

Desired:
application shows update-hint on top of every window, while application is in the foreground. Switching to another application will also send the update-hint to the background.

---

Desired: Update-Hint overlays ANY window of the current application:

[image]

Not desired: Update-Hint overlays FOREIGN applications as well:

[image]

Comment: Make sure the main form is the owner of the floating form.

Comment: Windows 10 has a Notification System for just this kind of thing. Your current itteration overlaps with this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110310-00/?p=11253

Comment: @Christopher That article is not what the OP issue is.

Comment: @LarsTech explicit setting the owner has no impact at all...

Comment: It should when you minimize your form.  Make TopMost = false, too, btw.

Comment: @LarsTech Yes, ofc. I could handle the "topmost" attribute manually all the time... But with potentially 200 different forms, I don't want to :P

Comment: I don't know what the issue is.  TopMost = false, and then when you show the form, make sure the owner is the main form: `updateForm.show(this);`

Comment: @LarsTech The "Form" is raised from within a thread, whenever an update is available. (checked every 15 minutes) - No matter how many forms are currently open, THIS form should be topmost (that's working so far) - but ONLY if "application" is in the foreground (that's not working - the Update-Hint will overlay Outlook, Word, excel... every application)

Comment: No, "this" needs to be the owner of the form.  You are mentioning something gibberish about 200 forms, so if that's the case, you would have to figure out which form should be the owner.

Comment: @LarsTech Dunno how to explain it: I need "topmost=true" as long as ANY window of your application is in the foreground. Else it should be "topmost=false".

Comment: @LarsTech: The article relates to how trying to make a "topmost" thing is a bad idea. I used it as a additional incentive to maybe use a Windows Function for this.

Comment: Try it in a new project.  Put a button on the main form.  In the click event, call `Form f = new Form();  f.Show(this);`  It will float, and hide when you minimize, and won't float above other applications when they get the focus.

Comment: @Christopher But the OP is NOT trying to make his floating forms the "Top Most" of all forms on the screen.  Exact opposite actually.  It's a great article, it just doesn't apply to this question.

Comment: Added 2 Screenshots, to make it (maybe) a little clearer.

Comment: Could you just make the update form a Midi form and forget about the Top-Most value? A midi form would work for what you have in the pics just fine.

Comment: I don't know how else to tell you.  TopMost = false, and show the "tip form" with an owner.  It will NOT float above the other applications.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII Midi Forms won't work out, as there are many different forms possible. (Everything would need to be a Midi form of the "Main-Form" which is impossible for many reasons, for example "Multi-Monitor-Support"...)

Comment: @dognose ok; then you'll need to monitor application focus and adjust the ```TopMost``` accordingly.  I'll try to work up an example.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII Yes, that'll work ofc.... Just hoped there is a more "handy" solution like `this.applicationTopMost=true` :P

Comment: That's a special property you have to custom write.  lol

Comment: It is not that clear to me why this is hard to do.  You should be able to figure out that there's an update quite quickly after the app starts.  So use the Show(owner) overload, using the main window as the owner.  If the app is long-running and tests frequently then NotifyIcon is appropriate.

Comment: @HansPassant Updating during startup is no issue. However, if users are "using" the application, I need to ensure 2 things: 1.) They are aware of updates available (I can force critical updates) 2.) The notification does not "mess" with their usual workflow. (Which a "TopMost-Overlay" does)

Comment: @LarsTech If you are sure, please provide some lines of codes as "answer" (I'd love to accept it :P )

Comment: Nobody is proposing you use TopMost.  So don't, keep it simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to solve it.

Setting the `owner` of the `UpdateHint` is required, but in order to keep it on top of every application window, one has to change the owner, if a new Window is either shown, or activated.

Within our application, every `Form` is inheriting `InterceptorForm`, so all I had to do was to modify the `InterceptorForm` accordingly:

Change the Owner to `this`, except if there is no dialog, or `this` is the dialog itself:

```
public class InterceptorForm : Form
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        ...

        if (this.GetType() != typeof(UpdateHint) && MainWindow.updateHint != null)
        {
            Log.t("Setting owner on update hint during onload: " + this.GetType());
            MainWindow.updateHint.Owner = this;
        }

        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
```

and

```
    protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.GetType() != typeof(UpdateHint) && MainWindow.updateHint != null)
        {
            Log.t("Setting owner on update hint: " + this.GetType());
            MainWindow.updateHint.Owner = this;
        }

        base.OnActivated(e);
    }
}
```

The `UpdateHint` now stays on top of every window belonging to our application, but can be overlayed by any other application.

Answer (score 4):

Despite the name of the property, TopMost is actually your enemy here.  To make a "floating form" stay above a main form, without obscuring other applications when they get focus, try it this way:

```
FormX f = new FormX();
f.Show(this);
```

"this" in this example, is the main form instance.  It means the form you created is now owned by the main form, and will make it float above it.  You get the added benefit of, when minimizing the main form, the floating forms will disappear, too.

Comment: Thanks for your example. This will work, if the "target" is to keep the floating form just on top of the main-window. However, this approach would allow "other" forms of the application to overlay the floating form - and obviously I can't call `f.Show(this)` for more than one form.

Comment: @dognose What you really want my man is to switch to WPF where problems like are long forgotten.

Comment: @dognose That's just a different issue.  I would re-think this whole update-floating-form concept and just show a toast notification or something else.  To be honest, annoying an end-user with the update form is just...annoying.

Comment: @LarsTech See my answer, I found a way to change the owner "easily" to handle this. Yep, it should be annoying, cause people should update. (especially those who never shutdown their pc and/or application)